# OpenGL slows down when rendering nearby objects on top of others

Tags: ios, c, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am writing an iOS app using OpenGL ES 2.0 to render a number of objects to the screen.
Currently, those objects are simple shapes (squares, spheres, and cylinders).

When none of the objects overlap each other, the program runs smoothly at 30 fps.

My problem arises when I add objects that appear behind the rest of my models (a background rectangle, for example).  When I attempt to draw a background rectangle, I can only draw objects in front of it that take up less than half the screen.  Any larger than that and the frame rate drops to between 15 and 20 fps.

As it stands, all of my models, including the background, are drawn with the following code:

```
- (void)drawSingleModel:(Model *)model
{
    //Create a model transform matrix.
    CC3GLMatrix *modelView = [CC3GLMatrix matrix];

    //Transform model view
    // ...
    //Pass matrix to shader.
    glUniformMatrix4fv(_modelViewUniform, 1, 0, modelView.glMatrix);

    //Bind the correct buffers to openGL.
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, [model vertexBuffer]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, [model indexBuffer]);
    glVertexAttribPointer(_positionSlot, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), 0);

    glVertexAttribPointer(_colorSlot, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid*) (sizeof(float) * 3));

    //Load vertex texture coordinate attributes into the texture buffer.
    glVertexAttribPointer(_texCoordSlot, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid*) (sizeof(float) * 7));
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, [model textureIndex]);
    glUniform1i(_textureUniform, 0);

    glDrawElements([model drawMode], [model numIndices], GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
}
```

This code is called from my draw method, which is defined as follows:

```
- (void)draw
{
    glUseProgram(_programHandle);
    //Perform OpenGL rendering here.
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

    _camera = [CC3GLMatrix matrix];

    //Camera orientation code.
    //...

    //Pass the camera matrix to the shader program.
    glUniformMatrix4fv(_projectionUniform, 1, 0, _camera.glMatrix);

    glViewport(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
    //Render the background.
    [self drawSingleModel:_background];

    //Render the objects.
    for(int x = 0; x < [_models count]; ++x)
    {
        [self drawSingleModel:[_models objectAtIndex:x]];
    }

    //Send the contents of the render buffer to the UI View.
    [_context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
}
```

I found that by changing the render order as follows:

```
    for(int x = 0; x < [_models count]; ++x)
    {
        [self drawSingleModel:[_models objectAtIndex:x]];
    } 
    [self drawSingleModel:_background];
```

my frame rate when rendering on top of the background is 30 fps.

Of course, the slowdown still occurs if any objects in _models must render in front of each other.  Additionally, rendering in this order causes translucent and transparent objects to be drawn black.

I'm still somewhat new to OpenGL, so I don't quite know where my problem lies.  My assumption is that there is a slowdown in performing depth testing, and I also realize I'm working on a mobile device.  But I can't believe that iOS devices are simply too slow to do this.  The program is only rendering 5 models, with around 180 triangles each.

Is there something I'm not seeing, or some sort of workaround for this?
Any suggestions or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You're running in one of the peculiarities of mobile GPUs: Those things (except the NVidia Tegra) don't do depth testing for hidden surface removal. Most mobile GPUs, including the one in the iPad are tile based rasterizers. The reason for this is to save memory bandwidth, because memory access is actually a power intensive operation. In the power constrained environment of a mobile device reducing required memory bandwidth gains significant battery lifetime.

Tile based renderers split up the viewport into a number of tiles. When sending geometry into it, it is split into the tiles and then for each tile it is intersected with the the geometry already in the tile. Most of the time the tile is covered by only a single primitive. If the incoming primitive happens to be in front of the already present geometry it replaces it. If there's a cutting intersection a new edge is added. Only if a certain threshold of number of edges is reached, that single tile will switch to depth testing mode.

Only at synchronization points the prepared tiles are rasterized, then.

Now it's obvious why overlapping objects reduce rendering performance: The more primitives overlap, the more preprocessing has to be done to setup the tiles.

Comment: My testing indicates that it does depth testing.

Comment: So, is there a workaround for this?  As I stated, my performance improves if I draw my background last.  So, it would appear that depth sorting my objects would help if I can do it fast enough.

Even so, that's all well and good for opaque objects, but it doesn't work for translucent once.  The performance reduction is just as bad when I render an overlapping translucent object.  I can't draw those front to back because, to my knowledge, there's no way to make OpenGL render them correctly if I do.

It seems like I'll have to avoid using transparency much more than I was hoping to.

Comment: @bindsniper001: Order independent transparency is a problem unsolved for primitive rasterizing renderers, as OpenGL is. The only workaround there is, is to preprocess your scene into a perfectly non-overdrawing set of primitives. This can be done with BSPs. However I wonder what your program does different than all those games running happily on the iPad, to have this performance hit.

Answer (score 1):

See "[transparency sorting](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Transparency_Sorting)"/"[alpha sorting](http://www.sjbaker.org/steve/omniv/alpha_sorting.html)".

I suspect the slowness you're seeing is largely due to "overdraw", i.e. framebuffer pixels being drawn more than once. This is worst when you draw the scene back-to-front, since the depth test always passes. While the iPhone 4/4S/5 may have a beefy GPU, last I checked the memory bandwidth was pretty terrible (I don't know how big the GPU cache is).

If you render front-to-back, the problem is that transparent pixels still write to the depth buffer, causing them to occlude polys behind them. You can reduce this slightly (but only slightly) using the alpha test.

The simple solution: Render opaque polys approximately front-to-back and then transparent polys back-to-front. This may mean making two passes through your scene, and ideally you want to sort the transparent polys which isn't that easy to do well.

I think it's also possible (in principle) to render everything front-to-back and perform alpha testing on the destination alpha, but I don't think OpenGL supports this.

Comment: No, that's not the issue here. See my answer.